# Switching from onecolumn to twocolumn sends to the next page!

Tags: page-breaking, two-column

I have a simple `documentclass` with `onecolumn` title and `twocolumn` body. When When switching back to `twocolumn` for the body text, it will goes to the next page instead of continuing under the title:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{article2}
\newcommand\@ptsize{}

\DeclareOption{letterpaper}
   {\setlength\paperheight {11in}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {8.5in}}

\DeclareOption{10pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{0}}

\DeclareOption{final}{\setlength\overfullrule{0pt}}
\DeclareOption{onecolumn}{\@twocolumnfalse}
\DeclareOption{twocolumn}{\@twocolumntrue}

\ExecuteOptions{letterpaper,10pt,twocolumn,final}
\ProcessOptions
\input{size1\@ptsize.clo}

\newenvironment{titlex}
    {%
        \onecolumn
    }%
\twocolumn
\endinput
```

How to switch back to `twocolumn` by continuing right after the title (in the same page).

**UPDATE:** My point is how to safely switch from `onecolumn` to `twocolumn` and vice versa. An example is putting a long formula in the middle of a two-column text.

Comment: Are you allowed to use [`multicol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol)? It allows for much easier switching between column formats.

Comment: @Werner `multicol` is sometimes very useful, but it is also limiting, for example when playing with figures within text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\twocolumn` allows to put one-column header stuff in an optional argument. So you could try

```
\twocolumn[header stuff]
```

Although the `\titlepage` definition looks strange to me. The whole idea of `\titlepage` is that it's on a page of its own.

Comment: I understand your point of titlepage, but it is not the issue here. I want to learn how switching from `onecolumn` to twocolumn works. Imagine we switch to `onecolumn` again to put a long formula within a `twocolumn` text.

Comment: The latter is not possible by using `\onecolumn` and `\twocolumn`. You can look at the `multicols` package or put your formulas in floating figures.